# How to decode two different values?

Tags: oracles, acurast

I am running two jobs which return different value. how to decode those value? for one job I am doing [like this](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/tanssi/blob/942de087f4a1f5d84a3dd23d87a5ecbd660962ce/container-chains/templates/simple/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1023). Someone please suggest me how to decode two jobs value?